# EMV choose crypto method between SDA/DDA/CDA

Tags: authentication, emv

I'm a newbie in emv world.

I'm trying to follow this flow:
[image: emv flow chart]

I'm in the third step. I have to manage the Offline Data Authentication.

How can I negotiate the correct way (SDA, DDA or CDA) with the ICC to perform offline auth?

Answer (score 1):

I got it.
You have to the AIP field as follows:
[image]

To retrieve the AIP, according to "EMV Book 3 - Application Specification", use te Tag 0x80 Format 1 reply for GET PROCESSING OPTIONS contained:

x82: Application Interchange Profile (AIP),
x94: Application File Locator (AFL).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123294/discussion-between-defalt-and-piero-alberto).